# Problems uploading folders containing files to FTP Server Python

Tags: python, ftp-client, ftplib, ftp-server

I am developing a FTP client and Server written in python. In my client's local directory it contains a folder containing many sub folders (E.G: C:/PatientRecords/A/, C:/PatientRecords/B/). Inside the sub folders it contains many files. I am trying to upload all the files including the folder structure to the server's directory in (D:/PatientRecords/A/, D:/PatientRecords/B/). I am using the FTPLIB library in this project. However the files that have been uploaded to the server ended up in the root of D drive. How do I go about creating directory on the server's directory?

```
with open(filename, "rb") as file:
ftp.storbinary("STOR " + filename", file)
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a directory, call the method `ftp.mkd(parameter)` with the parameter as the directory name, then call the `ftp.cwd()` method before writing. It changes the directory for the server, so specify the new folder path on your D:/ drive and drop it into the parameter for `ftp.cwd()`.

edit: here's the [library documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html) if you want it

Comment: oh but the D:/drive is an empty drive with no folders being created before hand. so i do something like ftp.cwd("D:/PatientRecords/A/")?

Comment: I just saw that you wanted to create a directory, that's my bad. I changed my answer above.

Comment: so i will have to call this statement ftp.mkd("D:/PatientRecords/A/") before i can do the upload?

Comment: Then you'd also might have to switch into it with the first method, `ftp.make()` doesn't say anything about switching into the directory on creation, so then you'd call `ftp.cwd()`

Comment: i see! second part of the question does this statement does a check if existing folder do exist before creation? or rather will it throw an exception if there is already an existing folder?

Comment: I would assume so (I've rarely used this library), it seems like good practice to check.

Comment: so cwd comes after mkd?

Comment: `cwd` does come after `mkd`